# Como hacer pull correctamente sin antes haber hecho un commit

Tags: git, git-commit, git-pull

Tengo algunas cambios que hice y aún no he hecho commit.

Intento hacer pull a la rama master para traerme los cambios actuales antes de yo hacer un push.

El problema es que no me deja hacer pull porque tengo cambios en local a los cuales no les he hecho un commit.

Entonces mi duda es la siguiente: Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacer un pull sin perder mis cambios, resolver conflictos (en caso de tenerlos) y luego hacer commit y posteriormente el push?

si hago un commit en este momento, luego hago un pull y posteriormente un push estaría subiendo todos los cambios que se bajaron en el pull o solo los que tenía hasta el commit ? la verdad estoy un poco enredado, recién comienzo con git.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias guardar tus cambios con un stash. Primero si los archivos que editaste/creaste no estan trackeados por git necesitas ejecutar:

`git add .` para agregar todos los archivos o puede agregar los que quieras

En tu rama actual ejecutas:

```
git stash
```

despues haces pull de la rama que quieras, ya que jalaste los ultimos cambios ejecutas

```
git stash pop
```

que lo que hace es sacar los ultimos cambios que guardaste con stash. Si tienes algun conflicto simplemente los resuelves haces tu `git commit` y puedes hacer `git push`. Y listo

imagina que con git stash guardas cambios en un arreglo y de hecho puedes mirar el listado de cambios que has guardado con:

```
git stash list
```

y puedes sacar cambios guardados de una pocion que desees usando:

```
git stash pop stash@{xposicion}
```

Y por ultimo, puedes nombrar los cambios que deseas guardar con:

```
git stash save "cambios de prueba"
```

esto es de ayuda para cuando has "stasheado" varias veces y puedas reconocerlos.

Comment: O si sólo quieres guardar y restaurar luego (por ejemplo para traer cambios sin que aún hayas terminado tus tareas), `git stash -u` , `git pull` y `git stash pop`.

Comment: @Isaac muchas gracias amigo. ahora tengo un pequeño problema. resulta que el visual studio code me marcar el archivo con cambios actuales y cambios entrantes. Debería aceptar todos los cambios actuales no? pero el problema es que no entiendo por que los cambios actuales me eliminan una parte del codigo que tengo si esa parte yo no la eliminé, los cambios que hice fueron solo agregar cosas, porque sucede esto? no logro entender eso.

Comment: Ya logré resolver ese problema que comenté. Ahora se me generó otra duda... habia modificado 4 archivos, hice el git stash save, luego git pull, git stash pop y resolví conflictos en 1 de esos 4 archivos, ahora si hago git status solo me aparece que modifiqué ese archivo solamente, y los otros 3 no van a aparecer reflejados cuando haga el commit? estoy confundido en es parte, podrías explicarme?

Comment: Que bueno que resolviste lo anterior.
Deberian aparecer los 4 archivos que modificaste como listo para commitear, ya que stash lo que hace es solo guardar los cambios que hayas hecho momentaneamente hasta que haces git stash pop. Cuando haces git stash pop simplemente aplicas los cambios que habias hecho, y deberian aparecer en tu commit.

Answer (score 1):

Preguntas

> Si hago un commit en este momento, luego hago un pull y posteriormente un push estaría subiendo todos los cambios que se bajaron en el pull o solo los que tenía hasta el commit ?

**Respuesta breve**: se subirán todos los cambios (en realidad los remotos ya estaban allí, de modo que se suben los locales, más el commit que mezcla éstos con los traídos por el pull)

### Respuesta detallada

Si haces un `git add` y `git commit` en este momento, guardarás en tu rama local todos tus cambios. Al hacer después un `pull`, se traerán los cambios de la rama remota y git hará automáticamente un *merge* entre ambas ramas, creando un nuevo commit que registra la mezcla de todo (y que de momento estará sólo en tu rama local).

Es posible que al intentar hacer hacer el *merge* se produzcan conflictos. Esto ocurrirá si los mismos ficheros que han sido modificados en tu rama local también han sido modificados en la rama remota. Si las modificaciones afectan a ficheros diferentes no habrá conflictos y lo que tendrás en local será el resultado final, conteniendo tanto tus cambios como los que has bajado con `pull`.

En caso de conflicto el *merge* no se completa, sino que queda "a medias". Debes entonces editar los ficheros en conflicto. Tendrán marcas señalando qué partes se cambiaron en local y cuáles en remoto. Examina los cambios, y modifica el fichero para eliminar esas marcas y dejar sólo la parte que te interese (local o remota). Una vez todos los ficheros en conflicto han sido editados y han quedado a tu gusto, harás un `commit`, que causará que el *merge* interrumpido se complete.

Al final de lo anterior (tanto si hubo conflictos como si no), tienes un repositorio "arreglado", que contiene tus cambios más los remotos y que has dejado a tu gusto. Si examinas la historia de este repositorio verás que contiene como *commit* más reciente uno en el que se juntan dos ramas: una de ellas tendrá tus commits locales y la otra los cambios commits remotos que habían bajado con el pull. Este es el commit del *merge* que `git` creó automáticamente.

Si en este momento haces un `push`, se enviará al repositorio remoto lo que faltaba en aquél, es decir, los commits locales y el commit del merge. En este punto tu repositorio local y el remoto tendrán ya la misma historia y todo estará arreglado.